# Validate that 2 angular Form fields do not have the same content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-validation

I have an angular form consisting of two fields location A and Location B. 
What I'd like to achieve is a directive that compares both fields and validates accordingly, style the valid or invalid field appropriately whenever the fields have the same location.

I have attempted inserting logic using `ng-change = validateLocations()` but based on what i've researched, a directive would be better suited for scenarios such is the above.The same logic could also be applied in validating `from` and `to` dates on a datepicker as well.

I tried something like this:

```
.directive("locationANotEqual", function () {

        return {

            restrict: "A",
           require: "ngModel",
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {

                ctrl.$validators.locationNotEqual= function (modelvalue) {
                    if (modelvalue !== scope.form.locationB) {
                        return true;

                    } else {

                        return false
                    }
                }
}
}
});
```

I put the attribute on the locationA input field  in this regard. 
What I'd like is to be able to incorporate checks for both fields in a single directive rather than 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another parameter to your directive and compare to that value instead of `scope.form.locationB`. Call [`attributes.$observe`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) on that value for changes so the model of the directive can be marked valid/invalid.

`data-ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` is used so that when the values do match, the model is still set.

```
app.directive('validateNotEqual', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            require: '^ngModel',
            link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModelCtrl) {
                if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                    return;
                }

                var errorKey = 'notEqual';

                ngModelCtrl.$validators[errorKey] = function(value) {
                    return value !== attributes.validateNotEqual;
                };

                attributes.$observe('validateNotEqual', function(value) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity(
                        errorKey,
                        value !== ngModelCtrl.$modelValue);
                });
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sk0oHS24pAKkYjVVhtKi?p=preview).

Comment: This worked for me . I modified  `ngModelCtrl.$validators[errorKey]` to `ngModelCtrl.$validators.notEqual`